# How to show additional column from sales_order_item to order view information

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order

I'm trying to show additional column in the `order view -> information` page this is the url page : `rootDomain/admin_an2/sales/order/view/order_id/40/key`.

[image]

From what I understand this data is coming from the `sales_order_item` table, now I have added additional column to that table called `expected_delivery_time` But I don't know how can show it there?

I found out that this UI is created from here : `/rootProject/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items $block
 */
$_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<div class="admin__table-wrapper">
    <table class="data-table admin__table-primary edit-order-table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
                <?php $i = 0;
                $columns = $block->getColumns();
                $lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>
                <?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnTitle):?>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    <th class="col-<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $columnName ?><?php /* @noEscape */ echo ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ' last' : '')?>"><span><?php /* @noEscape */ echo $columnTitle ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php $_items = $block->getItemsCollection();?>
        <?php $i = 0; foreach ($_items as $_item):?>
            <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $i++;
            }?>
            <tbody class="<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $i%2 ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>">
                <?php echo $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php echo $block->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item) ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried to find a block `Items` class.
I get the `getColumn()`  :

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getColumns()
{
    $columns = array_key_exists('columns', $this->_data) ? $this->_data['columns'] : [];
    return $columns;
}
```

How to add my column to the `$this->_data['columns']` ? getting stuck here.
any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a several hours finally I have found the solution. Here is the step :

- create layout `view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` like this :

  ```
      <referenceContainer name="left">
  <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs" name="sales_order_tabs">
      <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" name="order_tab_info" template="order/view/tab/info.phtml">
          <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Messages" name="order_messages"/>
          <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" name="order_info" template="order/view/info.phtml"/>
          <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="order/view/items.phtml">
              <arguments>
                  <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
                      <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
                      <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
                      <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                      <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                      <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                      <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
                      <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
                      <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
                      <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item>
                      <item name="expected-delivery-time-column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Expected Delivery Time</item>
                  </argument>
              </arguments>
              <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">
                  <arguments>
                      <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                          <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                          <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                          <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item>
                          <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                          <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                          <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                          <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                          <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                          <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                          <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                          <item name="expected-delivery-time" xsi:type="string" translate="true">col-expected-delivery-time</item>
                      </argument>
                  </arguments>
              </block>
              <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty" name="column_qty" template="items/column/qty.phtml" group="column"/>
              <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
              <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="order_item_extra_info"/>
          </block>

          <container name="payment_additional_info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="order-payment-additional" />
          <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Payment" name="order_payment"/>
          <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History" name="order_history" template="order/view/history.phtml"/>
          <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="gift_options" template="Magento_Sales::order/giftoptions.phtml">
              <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Giftmessage" name="order_giftmessage" template="order/view/giftmessage.phtml"/>
          </block>
          <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="order/totals.phtml">
              <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals\Tax" name="tax" template="order/totals/tax.phtml"/>
          </block>
      </block>
      <action method="addTab">
          <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_info</argument>
          <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">order_tab_info</argument>
      </action>
      <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices" name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container"/>
      <action method="addTab">
          <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_invoices</argument>
          <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_invoice.grid.container</argument>
      </action>
      <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos" name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container"/>
      <action method="addTab">
          <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_creditmemos</argument>
          <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container</argument>
      </action>
      <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments" name="sales_order_shipment.grid.container"/>
      <action method="addTab">
          <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_shipments</argument>
          <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_shipment.grid.container</argument>
      </action>
      <action method="addTab">
          <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_history</argument>
          <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History</argument>
      </action>
      <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions" name="sales_transactions.grid.container"/>
      <action method="addTab">
          <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_transactions</argument>
          <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_transactions.grid.container</argument>
      </action>
  </block>
  ```
- create plugin to override the method for showing the expected delivery date :

`use\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer`

```
class DefaultRendererPlugin
{
    public function aroundGetColumnHtml(DefaultRenderer $defaultRenderer, \Closure $proceed,\Magento\Framework\DataObject $item, $column, $field=null)
    {
        if ($column == 'expected-delivery-time'){
            $html = $item->getExpectedDeliveryTime();
            $result = $html;
        }else{
            if ($field){
                $result = $proceed($item,$column,$field);
            }else{
                $result = $proceed($item,$column);

            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

- etc config :

  ```
  <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer">
      <plugin name="fabelio-order-view-information" type="Fabelio\Sales\Plugin\DefaultRendererPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
  ```

that's it.

Comment: he, this will add the column, can we hide/disable if $item->getExpectedDeliveryTime() is empty or null

Comment: It is not displaying data for me, only display Column name

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have created 'custom_item_column' in sales_order_item table you can add a custom column to Items Grid in sales order view by following:

1.Create **sales_order_view.xml** file in `app/code/[Vendor]/[Modulename]/view/adminhtml/layout` folder and add the below code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_items">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_item_column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Item Column</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
        <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="custom_item_column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">col-custom_item_column</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn"
               name="column_custom_item_column"
               template="Namespace_Modulename::custom_item_column.phtml" group="column" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

2.Create "custom_item_column.phtml" file in [Namespace]/[Modulename]/view/adminhtml/templates folder and add the below code.

```
<span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __($block->getItem()->getData('custom_item_column')) ?></span>
```

source : https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/11076

Comment: How to make as first column in table

Comment: this will add the column, how can we hide/disable the coulmn based on certain condition?

Comment: that is, $block->getItem()->getData('custom_item_column'); is empty, then i need to hide column

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and searched for your solution and found below links.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958965/adding-new-column-in-sales-order-view-items-in-magento-admin.

Hope it helps.

=====================Edit my answer =====================.
I consider you have created expected_delivery_time column in "sales_order_item" table and saved value in this field when order place.

To display a value of this field makes below changes.

Create "sales_order_view.xml" file in [company/[module]/view/adminhtml/layout. and add below codes.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <referenceBlock name="order_items">
    <arguments>
                        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
                            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
                            <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
                            <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                            <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                            <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
                            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
                            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
                            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item>
                             <item name="exp_delivery_time" xsi:type="string" translate="true">expected delivery time</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                            <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item>
                            <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                            <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                            <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                             <item name="exp_delivery_time" xsi:type="string" translate="false">new-col-exp_delivery_time</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty" name="column_qty" template="items/column/qty.phtml" group="column"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="order_item_extra_info"/>
</referenceBlock>
</page>.
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks for giving this link, but my question still stands

Comment: Please check my editable answer

Comment: nope this doesn't show my `expected_delivery_time`  only the title column. but thanks upvoted

Comment: Thanks, Gujarat, I will look into this shortly and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a structure of module. In your **sales_order_view.xml** extended, put:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_tab_info">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
                        <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
                        <item name="custom_item_column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Item Column</item>
                        <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                        <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                        <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
                        <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
                        <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
                        <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" name="default_order_items_renderer" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                            <item name="custom_item_column" xsi:type="string" translate="true">col-custom_item_column</item>
                            <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                            <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                            <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty" name="column_qty" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/qty.phtml" group="column"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="order_item_extra_info"/>

                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn"
                       name="column_custom_item_column"
                       template="Namespace_Modulename::test.phtml" group="column" />
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, you can order or remove a column.